# Intercept HTTP requests

Tags: c#, java, c++, http

I've some fishy application that makes HTTP requests to a website, i would like to intersect that request and send other data to the server. Is that possible in C#,java or C++?

EDIT: The application isn't mine, i just know the endpoint that it sends http requests

Comment: What **intersect** actually means here?

Comment: You could write a proxy server and run it on your system. Configure the proxy server in your application (or in Internet Explorer, if the application is aware of these settings).

Comment: edited xD.  Uwe Keim but how do i "stop" the original request of being sended?

Comment: If you don't need to do it in code you can use a program like WireShark. And probably you can also use the WinPCap driver used by WireShark in your own program too.

Comment: I wonder if the program will respect your `hosts` file.

Comment: What program are you trying to intercept and change the data in?  Knowing that might help us provide better answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) might provide the functionality you need.  At the very least it may enable you to see what is being sent to the web site.

Comment: I think Fiddler will only allow you to introspect, but not modify.

Comment: Nop the fiddler only lets me see the requests

Comment: @DVD - On the contrary! Fiddler gives you the full power of Jscript.NET to tweak both the request and response to your heart's content! Here's a few examples: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/Dev/ScriptSamples.asp

Comment: but i want to do that programatically or using some kind of api xDD.

Answer (score 1):

in **Java** You can intercept request from  [Filter](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into using an HttpModule, whose purpose is to intercept incoming HTTP requests.

[The ASP Column: HTTP Modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301362.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly are you aware of how it is connecting to the internet? For example, is it using the settings from Internet Explorer, or is it establishing a direct connection? If the latter, this may be tricky, there is no direct port forwarding as there in Linux, so you'll need some third-party tools to redirect the traffic to a server (which you can write in Java, C++ or C#, I would go for C# if you know it for pure speed of development) In that server you can intercept the request, and then create your own to actually send to the real destination.

Sounds like a cludge, but I think you're stuck with this approach due to the lack of direct port forwarding. You'll have to configure the third-party tool that you use to forward someother well known port to 80, and your server should write to this.

Comment: The problem is that the program isn't mine so, i just know where it is sending data . . . What i would like to do is simply intercept that and do what i want xDD

Comment: @DVD, then you are stuck with the approach I mentioned above, in Java there are some embeddeble HTTP servers which are OS, then use the third-party tools (such as http://www.boutell.com/rinetd/ - this is old, a google search should return some newer tools!) to redirect the HTTP requests to your server, which should then send to the real destination (note, you'll have to redirect some local address to the real destination and your server should connect to that!)